# Data for Isoscape

Tags: open-data, mapping, database, isotopic

I am in the process of creating an isoscape for the stable isotopes in precipitation (<sup>2</sup>H and <sup>18</sup>O). Does anyone know of any other databases besides GNIP (IAEA) that have further entries (especially measured values for the period around 1950 to 1970)?

I know there is also the Bowen database: https://wateriso.utah.edu/waterisotopes/
but here I don't understand if it is possible to get the actual data.